# jQuery sortable manually Trigger the sortstop event

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it possible to manually trigger the [sortstop](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-stop) event of a jQuery sortable control?

I have tried `$(selector).trigger('sortstop')` but nothing seems to happen.

some of the relevant HTML:

```
<div data-zone="name">
    <div class="section disabled" id="section-1">Some section template 1</div>
    <div class="section" id="section-2">Some section template 2</div>
    <div class="section" id="section-3">Some section template 3</div>
</div>

<button class="trigger-button">Trigger stop</button>
```

and some of the JavaScript:

```
$("[data-zone]").sortable({
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    cancel : ".section.disabled",
    stop: function(){
       console.log('sort-stopped');        
    }
})

$(".trigger-button").click(function(){
    console.log('trigger-button clicked');
    var $zone = $('[data-zone]');
    console.log($zone);
    $zone.trigger('sortstop');
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/xCtqJ/12/) of the problem.

Comment: Why do you need to manually trigger sortstop?  Can't you just put the contents of the stop function in another function?  And call that second function directly?

Comment: The main issue is with closures in the code.  While I have a reference to the zone, there is a 'toggle move' per section that enables moving for that section.  I'm attempting to have a body click handler that will cancel the move, since all other controls are hidden.  I think I have solved it with a proper closure though.  I will update the jsfiddle in a moment

Answer (score 0):

Events are used by jQuery UI to notify your code that something has happened with their code, not the other way around.

You should be looking for **methods** that you can use to **control the sortable object** rather than trying to control ui elements by triggering events:

```
// Are you looking for this?
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "cancel" );

// Or this?
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "enable" );
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "disable" );
```

There is also no "sortstop" event. There is a "stop" event and a "beforeStop" event that sortables trigger when sorting is finished or about to finish, but these are sent out by the sortable object, not read by the sortable object in order to perform actions.

If what you really wanted was to listen for these events so you could perform some actions, then this is what you might want to do:

```
$("[data-zone]").on('stop', function(evt, ui) {
    // sortable has notified that it has stopped, do stuff here
});
```

More info can be found on the jQuery UI documentation for sortable:

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Also, here is the sortable.js source file on github

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js